# How would you make emacs write out line numbers into a file?

Tags: emacs

How would you go about writing a file from emacs that contains only the line numbers eg:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Ideally this would be a command that you would execute (how?) that can be told how many lines to print. Is this possible?

Comment: As an alternative to the `dotimes` approach, you could also use `number-sequence` and `mapconcat` to generate the content for the file as follows: `(mapconcat 'number-to-string (number-sequence 1 5) "\n")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a quick elisp function that does it:

```lisp
(defun write-line-numbers (n)
  (interactive "nNumber of lines: ")
  (save-excursion
    (with-output-to-temp-buffer "*lines*"
      (dotimes (line n)
        (princ (format "%d\n" (1+ line))))
      (set-buffer "*lines*")
      (write-file "lines.txt"))))
```

You would run it with `(write-line-numbers 8)` in elisp or with <kbd>M-x write-line-numbers 8</kbd> interactively.

Or you could save the above as a script and run emacs like so:

```
emacs -Q --script write-line-numbers.el --eval '(write-line-numbers 8)'
```

But as Moritz points out, there are better ways to do this outside of emacs.

Comment: Sorry I'm a complete newbie with emacs but where would I write the elisp function? How do you make these kind of functions available within emacs?

Comment: Put it in `.emacs` in your home directory and restart emacs.  Or type it into any buffer and run `eval-last-sexp` (`C-x C-e`) when the point is just after the final paren.  Yet another way is to run `eval-expression` (`M-:`) and type it in at the prompt.  The last two methods won't persist between emacs sessions.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use the shell program `seq` for it? E.g. `seq 20` will print 20 neat lines numbered 1 to 20.

Comment: I have upvoted you but not accepted the answer. Your answer is really useful to know but I am more interested in finding out more about how emacs works so even though it might not be the easiest way to fill a file with line numbers I want to know how to do it with emacs :)

Answer (score 2):

> <kbd>M-:</kbd>
>       (with-temp-file "foo.txt"
>         (dotimes (i 15) (insert (format "%2d\n" (1+ i)))))

If you do this often enough, make it a function:

```lisp
(defun write-sequence (length output-file)
  (interactive "nLength of sequence: \nFOutput file: ")
  (with-temp-file output-file
    (dotimes (i length) (insert (format "%d\n" (1+ i))))))
```